# Consistent plotting panel width/height when using gridExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to construct a 5 x 6 matrix of plots in R using ggplot2 and gridExtra.  For simplicity, I can show my issue with a 2 x 2 matrix and some fake data.

```
#Load libraries
  library(ggplot2); library(gridExtra)

#Data
  data = rbind(data.frame(x=rnorm(100,0,1),ALP='A',NUM=1),data.frame(x=rnorm(100,20000,1000),ALP='A',NUM=2),data.frame(x=rnorm(100,100,10),ALP='B',NUM=1),data.frame(x=rnorm(5000,1000),ALP='B',NUM=2))

#Ggplot2 facet_grid
  ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=..scaled..,fill='red')) + geom_density() + facet_grid(ALP~NUM,scales='free') + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

The result doesn't look good, as the x-scale is so different across the faceting labels.  I tried to do it manually with gridExtra.

```
#Assemble grobs
  plt1 = ggplot(subset(data,ALP=='A'&NUM==1),aes(x=x,y=..scaled..,fill=ALP)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(.~NUM,scales='free') + guides(fill=FALSE) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
  plt2 = ggplot(subset(data,ALP=='A'&NUM==2),aes(x=x,y=..scaled..,fill=ALP)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(ALP~NUM,scales='free') + guides(fill=FALSE) + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())
  plt3 = ggplot(subset(data,ALP=='B'&NUM==1),aes(x=x,y=..scaled..,fill=ALP)) + geom_density() + guides(fill=FALSE) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
  plt4 = ggplot(subset(data,ALP=='B'&NUM==2),aes(x=x,y=..scaled..,fill=ALP)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(ALP~.,scales='free') + guides(fill=FALSE) + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())

#Plot it out
  grid.arrange(plt1,plt2,plt3,plt4,nrow=2,ncol=2,left=textGrob("scaled",rot=90,vjust=1),bottom=textGrob("x"))
```

[image]

I'm almost there, unfortunately the plotting panel (x,y) in the upper, right-hand corner is smaller than all the rest.  Similarly, the plotting panel (x,y) in the lower, left-hand corner is bigger than all the rest.  I would like all of the plotting panels (x,y) to be the same height/width.  I found some code using gtable, but it only seems to work consistently when the grobs don't have facet labels.  The effect is even more exaggerated when the number of rows/columns increases.

Comment: easiest solution would be to use `facet_wrap(scales="free")`

Comment: @baptiste I really don't like the look of using facet_wrap(), as I have a lot of facets.  Oh well, I guess it is good enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an alternative to facetting, you could work with gtable,

```
plt <- lapply(list(plt1,plt2, plt3,plt4), ggplotGrob)

left <- rbind(plt[[1]], plt[[3]])
right <- rbind(plt[[2]], plt[[4]])
all <- cbind(left, right)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(all)
```

the panel sizes should all be equal (1null) with this layout.

[image]

Comment: When I try to replicate your example I get the following error **Error in unit(comp(x_val, y_val), x_unit): 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0**.  I'm running R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14); Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error occurred when I tried to run **all <- cbind(left, right)**.

Comment: works for me, maybe you have older packages, or loaded gtable before gridExtra.

Comment: I updated my version of R and downloaded that latest version of the packages.  Everything went smoothly.  Thanks!